# Whats the JQuery equivalent to the following PHP code? (JSON)

Tags: php, jquery, json, facebook, getjson

I got the following code in PHP:

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/192655950766049');
$data = json_decode($json, true);
echo $data['description'];
?>
```

and I want the equivalent code in JQuery.
I tried to do it myself but I had no luck.
Here's one of my many tries:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.getJSON("https://graph.facebook.com/192655950766049", function(json) {
   alert("JSON Data: " + json.description);
 });
</script>
```

I read the explanation from http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/, but yet I dont really understand it..

anyway, if you can help me it'll be very nice!

Thanks

Comment: I think it's not possible to eastablish a SSL encrypted connection using jQuery (https!!) Second problem is Same Origin Policy (SOP) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: @sled, I can reach the same page by using http

Comment: @sled, ajax calls are performed using the current scheme. If it's SSL or not it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use jquery's jsonp request. See [this](http://www.facebook.com/topic.php?uid=116742961708067&topic=61) short discussion on how to interface with facebook using this. JSONP allows for XSS ignoring the same origin policy.

Basically your code would then look similar to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.getJSON("https://graph.facebook.com/192655950766049?callback=?", function(json) {
   alert("JSON Data: " + json.description);
 });
</script>
```

Comment: so basiclly JSONP solves everything for me. thank you very much.

Comment: btw, I didnt understand, Do I need to make PHP file or I can use your code and thats it?

Answer (score 3):

You're violating the [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) by requesting a different domain with Javascript. You'll need to do this server side (i.e. with PHP in your case).

Comment: Understood. Thank you for the information. Btw, can I run JQuery getJSON on my php page (that will get the information using php geyJSON)?

Comment: Correct, if you really want this loaded dynamically, you can request a php page on your same domain with Javascript, and that page can make a request to Facebook and return the results.

Comment: Or use jsonp instead to get around the same origin limitation.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  var url = "https://graph.facebook.com/192655950766049?limit=3&callback=?";
  $.getJSON(url,function(json){
    var html = "<ul>";
    $.each(json.data,function(i,fb){
      html += "<li>" + fb.message + "</li>"; 
    });
    html += "</ul>";
    $('.facebookfeed').html(html);
  });
});
```

You can also check this url.
http://www.prettyklicks.com/blog/making-a-facebook-feed-using-the-graph-api-json-and-jquery/291/

Also check this link using the same method as i have specified.
[using $.getJSON within a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182649/using-getjson-within-a-loop)

Comment: thanks to wsanville I understood that I am violating "Same origin policy" and therfore I'll have to use php in this case. Unless I can get the data in php and then getJSON on my own php file.

Comment: I see you edited your answer just as I was posting about jsonp. Crap!

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to directly download data from facebook on the client side due to [cross site scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) limitations.

Answer (score 0):

In the event anyone is interested in using jquery locally IE: WAMP, here is a tested example.. The z.txt file it is reading has a simple single number in it..

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("z.txt", function(json) {
        alert(json);
    });
});
</script>
```